# CSS for this structure

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for a while to get the following structure playing with tables, float, align, position relative/absolute... but haven't succeed...

What CSS do I need for getting it?

The closest I've got have been using a table with three rows, and the second row had the chart and `A:lalala`, but then B was displayed too far to the bottom.

```
C:lololo (no chart title)
------------
|   chart  |         A: lalalal
|          |         B: lelelele
|__________|
```

This is the version with the table

```
 <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Check-in: </b>
                        <select id="dates" name="check_in" onchange="dynamicDates(this.value)">
                        <option value="check_in_date">Date</option>
                        <?php echo $dates; ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div style="max-width:400px" id="chart_div"</div>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p><b>Bookings: </b><?php echo $n_bookings; ?></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <p><b>Nights: </b><?php echo $nights; ?></p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Show us your html, please.  FYI, tables should not be used for layout.  There's far better methods.

Comment: @cale_b added the code I have right now, with the table

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing this - as seen with the answers. Another way can be seen in this jsfiddle example https://jsfiddle.net/33abzr9j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the love of all things beautiful, please DO NOT use tables for layout.

Since we don't know your layout (except for tables, which we won't be using for this answer), it's up for debate what the best method is.  Here's one of about a dozen different ways to tackle this solution:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/90pcocdo/)

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="chart_title">C: This is my title</div>
    <div class="chart">Chart goes here</div>
    <div class="extras">
        <div>A: This is row 1 to the right of chart</div>
        <div>B: This is row 2 to the right of chart</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.chart_title {
    font-weight: bold;
}

div.chart {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}

div.extras {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 58%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: just want to ask why it is encourage not to use tables for layout? how about registration form? table or series of div's? thanks. I'm not a web designer.

Comment: @FrancisSaul divs can be styled easier, can be mobile responsive, and a lot more that tables can't. Use a table if you need a table - but CDs has much better solutions. Speaking of grids, bootstrap has a really nice one that's pre built.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize the `float` css property as below

HTML

```
<div id='outer'>
    <p>Top Text</p>
    <div class='contents'>
        <div id='chart'>chart</div>
    </div>
    <div class='contents'>
        <ul>
            <li>abc</li>
            <li>abc</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}

    .contents {
        background-color:red;
        float:left;
        width:150px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    #chart {
        background-color:green;
        width:150px;
        height:150px;
    }
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o0ztm1fd/